# What does a.s. mean?

Tags: terminology

OK, so I know very little about Islam, but this question doesn't seem to be Google-able. I've seen some people in the Qur'an described with a.s. after their name - such as Nuh a.s.
What does that mean?

Answer (score 9):

"a.s." is short for "'**A**layhi al-**S**alaam" (عليه السلام), which is an Arabic phrase meaning "[Peace be upon him](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peace_be_upon_him)". It is often used by Muslims after the names of the prophets as a term of respect.

Answer (score 3):

As @goldPseudo correctly mentioned, "a.s." is the short form of "'Alayhi al-Salaam" (عليه السلام), which is an Arabic phrase and it means **"Peace be upon him**" and actually **it is often used by Muslims after the names of the prophets as a term of respect.**

On the other hand, as well as the front of prophets' names, it is often used by Shia Muslims for Shia Imams, too.
For instance:

**Imam Ali (a.s.) said ... So, it also means "peace be upon him" for Shia Imams.**

Answer (score 1):

A.S. means "Peace be Upon Him" used after the mention of Prophets and Angels (like Jibreel –Gabriel- A.S). As mentioned, Shia uses the term on their Imams. The term can be used on the Beloved Prophet Muhammad Salla llahu alay-hi wa sallam but (salla llahu alayh-hi wa sallam is recommended). See [Wikipedia for more on it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peace_be_upon_him).

Answer (score -2):

A.S means salla llahu alayh-hi wa sallam

Comment: Hm. why is it A.S. then and not S.L.A.W.S. elaborate and read [answer].